# Dialog losing focus when selecting file from browse

Tags: swt, jface

When i select the file from Directory iam lossing the focus from the Dialog.The Dialog screen is getting minimized.

```
btnSaveAs.setText("Browse...");

    btnSaveAs.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.RIGHT, SWT.CENTER, false,
            false, 1, 1));

    registerListeners();

    btnSaveAs.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(new Shell());
            dialog.setFilterPath("::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}");
            dialog.setText("Select a directory");
            dialog.setMessage(getBrowseDirectoryMessage());
            dialog.getParent().setSize(300, 300);

            String path = dialog.open();
            if (path != null) {
                model.setFilePath(path);
            }
        }
    });
```

File Model:

```
public IObservableValue outputPath          = new WritableValue(DataRealm.getRealm(), null, String.class);
```

What can be the case that the Dialog should not lose the Focus.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```java
dialog.getParent().setSize(300, 300)
```

is changing the size of the current dialog to be quite small. Remove this line.

Comment: Even when i remove ,...After selecting the file from path and click Ok..the dialog is minimizing...